# Is there any way to upgrade a SP2010 dev workstation to SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I've got SharePoint 2010 Foundation installed on my Windows 7 laptop, which I use as a dev workstation. In order to install SP2010 on Win7, you have to add the "AllowWindowsClientInstall" setting into the config file, which then prevents the install from kicking back the "requires Windows Server OS" error.

I know that the config setting trick above no longer works with SP2013, but is there any other way to simply upgrade my current setup to SP2013? Or is 2013 locked out in such a way that I absolutely have to have a server OS to install it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We support installation of SharePoint 2013 only on Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 x64 or Windows Server 2012. If you want to develop apps for SharePoint for SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7 or Windows 8, you can sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site and develop apps remotely. See [How to: Set up an environment for developing apps for SharePoint on Office 365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161179.aspx) for instructions about how to create this sort of development environment.

So, you best options are either go for Windows 8 and create VM

Check out this video: [Setting up team development infrastructure for SharePoint 2013 development](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/setting-up-team-development-infrastructure-for-sharepoint-2013-development/10tcd4al4)

Or User the 365.

You can also Use the Trial version of Windows server.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-trial.aspx

Comment: I was afraid of that... thank you for confirming, though.